# why annotating with @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, java-annotations

I'm reading Spring in Action 5th Edition. in part 4 (securing spring), he wanted to overide the security autoconfigured by spring boot... so he created a config class called it SecurityConfig as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

also, in the [Javadoc of @EnableWebSecurity](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/5.7.2/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) , they do the same thing

and they also say:

> Add this annotation to an @Configuration class to have the Spring Security configuration defined in any WebSecurityConfigurer or more likely by extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter base class and overriding individual methods

but @EnableWebSecurity is already a @Configuration. here is the code that confirms this:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Documented
@Import({WebSecurityConfiguration.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.SpringWebMvcImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.class})
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@Configuration
public @interface EnableWebSecurity
```

my question is why we should annotate a class with both @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity instead of just @EnableWebSecurity?

thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to annotate your `@EnableWebSecurity` class with `@Configuration` since [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/3171cc4364d953d880e4f5ca0f696e0af383d7b8#diff-80d0bdc1f06d2c405ab60d14c26a7c9039c1f8c760246e3b23594dada42c3ee8) commit.

As [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3014) says,

> This removes the need to state @Configuration when using @Enable* annotations.

So, seems like developers had removed the requirement to use both `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity`, but forgot to reflect this in JavaDoc.